# Passing only types marked as reified to Kotlin generic function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Let's say I have the following code:

```
open class Fruit
class Apple : Fruit()
open class Juice<T : Fruit>
class AppleJuice : Juice<Apple>()

fun <F : Fruit, J : Juice<F>> makeJuice(juiceClass : Class<J>, fruit : F) : J {}
```

I call the function like this:

```
val appleJuice : AppleJuice = makeJuice(AppleJuice::class.java, Apple())
```

But instead of passing a class object I would like to pass `AppleJuice` as a type:

```
val appleJuice : AppleJuice = makeJuice<AppleJuice>(Apple())
```

I have refactored my function to inline with `reified`:

```
inline fun <F : Fruit, reified J : Juice<F>> makeJuice(fruit : F) : J {}
```

But now I have to specify both types:

```
val appleJuice : AppleJuice = makeJuice<Apple, AppleJuice>(Apple())
```

In theory, `Apple` type shouldn't be needed because it's already known from `AppleJuice` type. Is it somehow possible to get rid of passing unnecessary types and pass only those maked as `reified`?

Comment: Is it possible to place `makeJuice` function inside `Juice` class in this case?

Comment: if it doesn't matter which `Fruit` you actually pass in, then you could just remove `F` and use `Juice<out Fruit>` and a `Fruit` parameter instead.

Comment: @Mosius No, it's not possible. It must be a static method

Comment: extension functions are also static methods... are extension functions ok? ;-)

Comment: @Roland It matters for me. I am doing some assignments in the method and it must be of the same as `Juice` generic

Comment: @Roland Well, it would be better to have just a simple static method. But if it's not possible, then an extension function is fine.

Comment: well... I don't think that you can have a single static function with reified type the way you want it to (i.e. where you actually require 2 generic types). Variant 3 in my answer is probably the best you can get without writing lots of additional implementations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem I see with your solution is, that you are asking for 2 generic types on your `makeJuice`-method. Both `F` and `J` need to be given to the function. While it is obvious for you (and anyone looking at the method), I think it might not be that obvious during runtime when the generic types are erased (but that is now mainly a guess here).

If you do not mind that the fruits you are passing are not really matching subtypes of the juice you are expecting then the following may be something for you:

```
inline fun <reified J : Juice<out Fruit>> makeJuice(fruit : Fruit) : J = TODO()
```

If however you want to ensure that `AppleJuice` can only be constructed with `Apple`s, then I can only think of solutions similar to the following:

1. adding the `makeJuice` to the `Fruit` classes, e.g.

   ```
   abstract class Fruit {
     abstract fun makeJuice() : Juice<out Fruit>
   }
   // and subclasses:
   class Apple : Fruit() {
     override fun makeJuice(): AppleJuice = TODO()
   }
   ```
2. adding a `makeJuice` (/`makeFrom`?) to the `Juice` classes, e.g.

   ```
   open class Juice<T : Fruit> {
     fun makeFrom(fruit : T) { TODO() }
   }
   ```
3. adding any other intermediate object so that you do not require 2 generic types at once, e.g.

   ```
   class JuiceMaker<F : Fruit>(val fruit : F) {
     inline fun <reified J : Juice<F>> makeJuice() : J = TODO()
   }
   fun <F : Fruit> using(fruit : F) = JuiceMaker(fruit)
   ```

   and calling it with

   ```
   using(Apple()).makeJuice<AppleJuice>()
   ```
4. variants of the above using extension functions, e.g.

   ```
   inline fun <reified J : Juice<out Apple>> Apple.makeJuice() : J = TODO()
   ```

   but you need to specify it for all types. The following unfortunately will not work:

   ```
   inline fun <F : Fruit, reified J : Juice<F>> F.makeJuice() : J = TODO()
   ```

   as we then have the same problem again... and need to specify `<Apple, AppleJuice>`.

But maybe none of these are what you were hoping to get.
So if you want to have a single method that handles it all, the third variant is probably your best choice (even though it uses a wrapper).